# How to create correct InstanceDescriptor for initializing some properties

Tags: c#, .net, typeconverter

Lets say I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo {}

    public int Titi { get; set; }
    public int Toto { get; set; }
    public int Tata { get; set; }
}
```

I can initialize a new instance like this:

```
var inst = new Foo { Titi = 12, Toto = 42, Tata = 421 };
```

But how can I create correct instance descriptor that performs same initialization as above?

```
public class FooConverter : TypeConverter
{
    // ...

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
                                     CultureInfo culture, 
                                     object value, 
                                     Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor) && value is Foo)
        {
            // Incorrect example because properties wont 
            // be initialized to 12, 42 and 421
            var ctor = typeof(Foo).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes); 

            return new InstanceDescriptor(ctor, null);
         }

         // ...
    }
}
```

NB1: I'm asking this because I want to create a TypeConverter for 'Foo' class and need to provide convertion to 'InstanceDescriptor'

NB2: Yes, I can add a constructor to Foo class that takes 3 arguments, but would like to avoid this and also would like to know which "construction description" corresponds to above sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to use but it seem that InstanceDescriptor don't only take constructors so you could do something like this :

```
public static class FooSerialization
{
    public static Foo CreateDesignFooInstance()
    {
        return new Foo { Titi = 12, Toto = 42, Tata = 421 };
    }
}
```

And then :

```
var m = typeof(FooSerialization).GetMethod("CreateDesignFooInstance", 
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
var desc = new InstanceDescriptor(m, null);
```

Comment: Yes, I saw I can also use MemberInfo, PropertyInfo ... trying something like this even if not too familiar with it and will let you know

Comment: Visual studio designer still crashing when working with 'Foo' class anyhow tested separatly your solution for implementing FooConverter and it is fine. Did it in this way `public static Foo ConvertToInstance(Foo inst)
        {
            return inst.Clone();
        }` and `if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor) && value is Foo)
            {
                var m = typeof(FooConverter).GetMethod("ConvertToInstance", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

                return new InstanceDescriptor(m, new object[] { value });
            }`